# Extend the width of the ViewBox while extending the window size

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml, winui-3, winui

How can I extend the width of the ViewBox while increasing the width of the window?

For privacy reasons I cannot publish the source code.

As the **Left Space** increases, the **Right Space** (**ViewBox**) should increase in its width, so the there isn't so much **Left Space**

**↡↡ Left Space**   ————   **Right Space ↡↡**

[image: Problem Of The GIF]

Comment: You don't have to publish your private source code. Create an example app that demonstrates the problem and publish that.

Answer (score 0):

> Extend the width of the ViewBox while extending the window size

The problem looks you specific current Viewbox `HorizontalAlignment` as Right, please find this property and set it as `Stretch`

```
<Viewbox StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
```

Comment: Hi, these are the properties, there doesn't seem to be an effect.

`<Viewbox StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Viewbox>`

Comment: It should be like that (see GIF, below):

https://imgur.com/a/4D0HVNH

Comment: why you use viewbox, can you use grid container to replace?

Comment: You also used Viewbox in your answer.

Comment: Yep, there is no need place viewbox for implementing the effect like your screenshot.